# Custom ErrorController not working with resourcesHandler?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm create an error controller like that:

```
@Controller
class ErrorController : org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping
    fun handlerError(): String {
        return "component/error"
    }

    override fun getErrorPath(): String {
        return "error"
    }
}
```

and when I restart my project, I found the default resources handler is not working(it works before I create this error controller)!
my resources folder structure:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/offKo.png)

It's not working even I override the addResourceHandler in WebMvcConfiguration:

```
override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**")
        .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_PUBLIC_RESOURCE_LOCATION)
    registry.addResourceHandler("/private/**")
        .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_PRIVATE_RESOURCE_LOCATION)
}
```

**If I remove the ErrorController, everything is ok!**

**In my opinion**, they should be able to work at the same time.
I googled it but didn't found anyone ask the same question(**maybe I missed it?**), so, anyone tell me **why** and **how**?
**Thank you so much!!!**

**Resolved:** 
It's my mistake, I didn't add a value to the `@RequestMapping` in the `ErrorController`, just change the code to:

```
@Controller
class ErrorController : org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    fun handlerError(): String {
        return "component/error"
    }

    override fun getErrorPath(): String {
        return "error"
    }
}
```